# Flutter how to update listview with data from streambuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have a widget with a streambuilder that gets data from firebase. I want to show this data in a listview that is in another widget but it doesn´t show up in the listview. Here is my code:

```
Widget _buildStream(BuildContext context){
return StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('markers').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
               productMap.add(snapshot.data.documents[i]['name']);
               
            }
            return _buildGoogleMap(context);
}
);}
```

And the other widget with the listview:

```
Widget _panel(ScrollController sc){
return MediaQuery.removePadding(
  context: context,
  removeTop: true,
  child: ListView(
    controller: sc,
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(height: 12.0,),

      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 30,
            height: 5,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0))
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 18.0,),
      ListView.builder(
                          primary: false,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount:
                              productMap == null ? 0 : productMap.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return new GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                              },
                              child: Card(
                                  child: ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage:
                                      AssetImage('asset/green.png'),
                                ),
                                title: Text(productMap[index]),
                              )),
                            );
                          },
                        )
    ],
  )
);
}
```

The listview is empty even if productMap contains data. What can I do do fix it?

Comment: once you have added data to the *list* call setState(). This will rebuild the Ui with updated data.

Comment: Okey, I have tried: setState(() {
                    productMap.add(snapshot.data.documents[i]['name']);
                    }); But then I get errors.